# rendering SDL2 function

Tags: c, sdl-2

Hello i have got problem with rendering my character i think i am wrongly passing arguments of function because debugger tells me that my height of image is 1854382513251 :D
But i don't know what I do bad. If smb could help me it would be nice.
Here is my code.

```
Wydruk_postaci(&P1, &NPCprzod, &NPCtyl, &NPCbok, &Renderer, &klatki);

            void Wydruk_postaci(Postac *P,sTekstura *Przod[2],sTekstura *Tyl[2],sTekstura *Bok[2],SDL_Renderer **Renderer,int *frame)
        {
            char position = 'F';
            if ((*P).predkoscx > 0)
            {
                render((*P).pozycjax, (*P).pozycjay, &(Bok[(*frame) / 4]), &Renderer, NULL);
                position = 'S';
            }
            if ((*P).predkoscx < 0)
            {
                render((*P).pozycjax, (*P).pozycjay, &(Bok[(*frame) / 4]), &Renderer, NULL);
                position = 'S';
            }
            if ((*P).predkoscy > 0)
            {
                render((*P).pozycjax, (*P).pozycjay, &(Przod[(*frame) / 4]), &Renderer, NULL);
                position = 'F';
            }
            if ((*P).predkoscy < 0)
            {
                render((*P).pozycjax, (*P).pozycjay, &(Tyl[(*frame) / 4]), &Renderer, NULL);
                position = 'B';
            }
            if((*P).predkoscx==0 && (*P).predkoscy==0)
            {
                if (position == 'F')
                {
                    render((*P).pozycjax, (*P).pozycjay, &(Przod[(*frame) / 4]), &Renderer, NULL);
                }
            }
            ++(*frame);
            if ((*frame) / 4 >= ILOSC_ANIMACJI)
            {
                (*frame) = 0;
            }
        }
```

render function is working correctly because i use it with other images in other functions. This one is a bit more complicated. Iknow that if i want it to work perfectly correct i should pass argument wiht position also but firstly this line

```
if((*P).predkoscx==0 && (*P).predkoscy==0)
            {
                if (position == 'F')
                {
                    render((*P).pozycjax, (*P).pozycjay, &(Przod[0]), &Renderer, NULL);
                }
            }
```

has to work but it doesn't.
Nothing appears on the screen if i have got this order in main function

```
        Poruszanie(&P1);



                        render(0, 0, &TloGra, &Renderer,NULL);

                        for (int i = 0,x=x_sciany,y=y_sciany ; i < 17; i++)
                        {
                            render(x, y, &Sciana, &Renderer, &Pomniejszacz);
                            x += 50;
                        }
                        for (int i = 0, x = x_sciany, y = y_sciany+50; i < 12; i++)
                        {
                            render(x, y, &Sciana, &Renderer, &Pomniejszacz);
                            y += 50;
                        }
                        for (int i = 0, x = x_sciany+800, y = y_sciany+50; i < 12; i++)
                        {
                            render(x, y, &Sciana, &Renderer, &Pomniejszacz);
                            y += 50;
                        }
                        for (int i = 0, x = x_sciany + 50, y = y_sciany + 600; i < 15; i++)
                        {
                            render(x, y, &Sciana, &Renderer, &Pomniejszacz);
                            x += 50;
                        }
                        for (int i = 0, x = x_sciany + 100, y = y_sciany + 100; i < 5; i++)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                            {
                                render(x, y, &Sciana, &Renderer, &Pomniejszacz);
                                x += 100;
                            }
                            x -= 700;
                            y += 100;
                        }
                        Wydruk_postaci(&P1, &NPCprzod, &NPCtyl, &NPCbok, &Renderer, &klatki);



                    }
                    SDL_RenderPresent(Renderer);
```

basically what the program is doing earlier, it is rendering objects on map.

Comment: If you're getting a big random number is probably uninitialized memory. Check you're loading your texture/surface correctly. If you can't find the problem I encourage you to try writing a minimal complete verifiable (this mean we can compile right away) example.

Comment: texture/surface is loaded correctly, because if i want to render the same objects in my main function by function "render" everything is okay.
Problem occurs if i try to render it by function "Wydruk_Postaci". There is no information about memory leaks i think still it's problem only in passing arguments. And also sometimes there are good dimensions of the object f.ex. 400:400 and sometimes there are random numbers.However I cant see on screen my object anyways

Comment: Uff i found a problem if smb is curious I wrongly passed Renderer to render function. There should be 
&(*Renderer) instead of pure &Renderer